# pwmconfig can't find fans, which are modifiable in uefi Bios

Tags: kernel-modules, sensors, fan

I would like to change the fan speeds on my PC. In the Asus BIOS settings, this is possible with PWM and DC (three of them are connected with 4 pins), but the running operating system seems to have problems doing the same.

The two I want to change manually have the names CHA_1FAN and CHA_2FAN on the motherboard.

```
> cat /etc/sensors3.conf | grep -i fan
    # Fans
        label fan1 "PSU Fan"
        label fan2 "CPU Fan"
        label fan3 "System FAN2"
        label fan4 "System FAN3"
        label fan5 "System FAN4"
    # Fans
        label fan1 "CPU Fan"
        label fan2 "System FAN2"
        label fan3 "System FAN3"
        label fan4 "System FAN4"
        label fan7 "PSU Fan"

   > hwinfo | grep -i fan
            acpi-fan: /devices/platform/PNP0C0B:03
            acpi-fan: /devices/platform/PNP0C0B:01
            acpi-fan: /devices/platform/PNP0C0B:04
            acpi-fan: /devices/platform/PNP0C0B:02
            acpi-fan: /devices/platform/PNP0C0B:00
            acpi-fan: module = fan
        type = "", modalias = "acpi:PNP0C0B:", driver = "acpi-fan"
        type = "", modalias = "acpi:PNP0C0B:", driver = "acpi-fan"
        type = "", modalias = "acpi:PNP0C0B:", driver = "acpi-fan"
        type = "", modalias = "acpi:PNP0C0B:", driver = "acpi-fan"
        type = "", modalias = "acpi:PNP0C0B:", driver = "acpi-fan"
      E: DRIVER=acpi-fan
      E: DRIVER=acpi-fan
      E: DRIVER=acpi-fan
      E: DRIVER=acpi-fan
      E: DRIVER=acpi-fan
      <6>[  0.062442] rcu: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=4
      fan 20480 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000
        Driver Status: thermal,fan are active
        Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe thermal; modprobe fan"
> sudo pwmconfig
[sudo] password for root:
# pwmconfig revision $Revision$ ($Date$)
[...]
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
heimchen@DESKTOP-G0NG8DL / [1]>
```

The system is OpenSuse Leap 15.5 and lm-sensor does not seem to be installed. I tried downloading it from source and compile it, which worked but there is still nothing with this name on my disk.

Answer (score 0):

[lm-sensors](https://hwmon.wiki.kernel.org/) is not a single tool, but a package of tools. For example, the `pwmconfig` command *is* part of lm-sensors, so your assumption that "lm-sensors does not seem to be installed" is not correct: since `pwmconfig` exists on your system, then lm-sensors must be installed, one way or another.

The `acpi-fan` listed in your `hwinfo` output is not very useful: it basically allows you to make gentle suggestions to your system firmware about how much cooling you think you'll need. If the firmware thinks the system needs more cooling than what you're suggesting, it is completely free to ignore your suggestions.

For `pwmconfig`-based fan control, you first need to identify and load a *sensor chip driver* appropriate to your system; usually such a chip also contains the speed control hardware for any software-controllable fans. The easiest and the safest way to do that is probably to run `sensors-detect` as root. It will ask a number of questions about which detection methods to run; on a regular desktop system, you can just accept the defaults.

If `sensors-detect` found any sensors and/or PWM devices, it will offer to create a file that will automate loading the drivers for them at boot.

In a unmodified upstream source, the file seems to get created according to Fedora/RedHat conventions; other distributions may include distribution-specific patches to modify this part to match the distribution's own configuration file conventions.

So, until you're more familiar with lm-sensors and kernel modules in general, try the distribution's own version of `sensors-detect` first. If you try a newer version from unmodified upstream releases (or even the bleeding-edge latest development version from their Git repository), be aware that its way to configure module autoloading might not do it the way your distribution expects it to be done. You might have to configure the module autoloading yourself.

If `sensors-detect` was successful, the `sensors` command should now be able to show you a block of voltages, temperatures and fan speed values it previously couldn't. This is a critical pre-requisite for you: if `sensors` cannot monitor your fans, then `pwmconfig` certainly won't be able to adjust them.

---

### Asus-specific bad news... sort of

Historically, the I/O addresses of the sensor chips used to be freely accessible to the running operating system kernel on most desktop motherboards. Currently Asus seems to be deviating from this convention: modern Asus motherboards increasingly mark the sensor chip registers as "controlled by firmware, don't touch" in the ACPI firmware data tables... and Linux will respect those marks by default. (Overriding them is possible, but at your own risk.)

Instead, Asus seems to provide a firmware-based (ACPI/WMI) interface that allows coordinated access to the sensor chip by both the firmware itself and by the running OS, which is a good idea if well implemented. Unfortunately, Asus seems to have tried several variations of the interface, and the Linux hardware monitoring developers don't yet have a complete list of which access method should be used with each Asus motherboard model. Also, the driver code for some of those access methods is still considered somewhat experimental.

As the information is gathered by basically people telling the developers what they had to do to make hardware monitoring and fan control work for their motherboards, the situation is slowly improving... but in the worst case, you might need a newer kernel version or even a (simple) custom kernel patch to tell the kernel to use a particular Asus-specific monitoring chip interface with your motherboard model.

---

### Specifics for Asus Z97 series motherboards

According to [this message on the lm-sensors developers mailing list](https://www.spinics.net/lists/lm-sensors/msg42494.html), the HW monitoring/PWM fan control chip on Asus Z97 series seems to be a Nuvoton NCT6791D, which is supported by the `nct6775` kernel module.

At the time of this writing, that motherboard is not listed in the newest kernel's [lists of Asus-specific ACPI access methods](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/hwmon/nct6775-platform.c?h=v6.4#n1054) for the hardware monitoring chip, so there is a chance you'll just need to load the module with

```
sudo modprobe nct6775
```

and you should see a new group in `sensors` output that should start with a line like:

```
nct6791-isa-0290
```

If it works, you'll need to configure that module to be loaded automatically at boot time to make the driver persistently available:

```
echo "nct6775" | sudo tee /etc/modules-load.d/hwmon.conf
```

If you don't see the `nct6791-isa-0290` group in `sensors` output, your system might require using the newer access methods, but the kernel does not know it yet. In this case, you might be able to allow old-style access by adding the kernel boot parameter `acpi_enforce_resources=lax`, **at your own risk.** If you use this, the kernel will output a message in `dmesg` to remind you that using the newer methods instead would be a better idea, if possible.

For testing, you might want to use the GRUB menu to add this boot parameter to the `linux` line of GRUB configuration for your current boot option, but if it works for you and has no harmful side effects, you could add it to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` variable in `/etc/default/grub`, and update your GRUB configuration to make it persistent.

After booting with the kernel boot option added, try loading the module again, and see if `sensors` now shows the information from the monitoring chip. If it does, you can make the module loading persistent, as above.

From the mailing list message linked above, you can also get a configuration block for your `/etc/sensors3.conf` that includes the (hopefully) correct scaling values for the voltage monitoring channels of the monitoring chip. After modifying the configuration file, run `sudo sensors --set` to make the new scaling values effective.

Comment: My sensors output:
```acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +34.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +31.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +33.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)```
My Asus Motherboard is from the year 2015, where could I look if its possible to control fans on this motherboard.

Comment: Looks like there is no sensors/PWM chip listed in the `sensors` output, just ACPI and the sensors in the CPU itself. Please identify the exact model of the motherboard: what is the output of`dmidecode -s baseboard-product-name`?

Comment: Z97-K, the fans are BZBYCZH 40mm, they can change their speed with pwm while the system is running if I let Q-Fan control them.(Q-Fan does not give me the option to couple them with my GPU, which itself has no fans)